# PHP echo automatically replaces "&" with "&amp;"

Tags: php, html, echo, ampersand

I'm making a PHP function that converts a $_GET array into the URL string format..

e.g. `Array('key1'=>'value1', 'key2'=>'value2')`
gets converted to: `?key1=value1&key2=value2`

I think the function it's doing its work correctly. But when I echo the result, in the HTML page all instances of "`&`" are replaced by "`&amp;`". So, the conversion in the browser ends up being `?key1=value1&amp;key2=value2`.

Here's my PHP function:

```
/**
 *
 * @param Array $GETArray Pass in the associative $_GET array here.
 * @return string The $GETArray converted into ?key=value&key2=value2&... form. 
 */
function strGET($GETArray) {
    if (sizeof($GETArray) < 1) {
        return '';
    }

    $firstkey = key($GETArray);
    $firstvalue = $GETArray[$firstkey];

    $sofar = "?$firstkey=$firstvalue";

    array_shift($GETArray);

    foreach ($GETArray as $key => $value) {
        $sofar .= '&'."$key=$value";
    }
    return $sofar;
}
```

Comment: I think we'll need the function to see. Basically unless explicitly told to, PHP shouldn't format your text automatically.

Comment: Thanks, I've added the code of my function in the question.

Comment: Ampersands should be `&amp;` in your markup. Changing it would be wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove &amp from string when writing to xml in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379283/remove-amp-from-string-when-writing-to-xml-in-php)

Comment: Yeah, your code looks fine. I don't see why that happens.

Comment: Yes, the code actually works, lol. It's my bad. The problem was that I'm using Google Chrome's Inspector to check my HTML, which ofcourse since it's written in javascript, it ends up converting the & in the html to &amp;... But when I viewed source (just now), it is actually outputting the correct thing. I'm now using http_build_query to do this, thanks to the answers below. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sidestepping your question, but use [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php). It does exactly that.

Also, your function does not HTML-escape anything. Neither does PHP by itself. You must be escaping it somewhere. Which, BTW, is correct. Ampersands should be escaped.

Comment: Thanks, it's always good to find out PHP writes a lot of your functions for you :P .. But back to my problem, it wasn't actually a problem! It was the code inspector I was using lol. See question comments above if interested..

Answer (score 0):

Use http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php function instead.